# Using SQLite lib for a c program with STM32cubeIDE in MacOS Monterey 12.5

Tags: c, macos, sqlite

I am trying to code a program in C and I need to add a light database.
I decided to go with SQlite but I am encountered some issues.
I am working in the STM32cubeIDE and running MACOS Monterey 12.5.
I have the sqlite3.a file and I added to the project-properties-build-settings-libraries the path to the folder and the file name without the lib and the .a.
Regarding the library file,  I compiled it myself (based on the amalgam folder that can be downloaded), but I also tried the version that you can get with brew. I installed also the command tool for mac and that works, I even create some tables in a database with the Sqlitestudio.

In any case, the result when I tried the simplest code is always the same:

```
10:48:21 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project PrototypeMica_v1 ****
make -j9 all 
arm-none-eabi-gcc -o "PrototypeMica_v1.elf" @"objects.list"  -Wl,--start-group -lsqlite3 -Wl,--end-group -mcpu=cortex-m4 -T"/Users/cristina.paniagua/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.12.0/PrototypeMica_v1/STM32L4P5ZGTX_FLASH.ld" --specs=nosys.specs -Wl,-Map="PrototypeMica_v1.map" -Wl,--gc-sections -static -L/Users/cristina.paniagua/Documents/SoSChiplet/Code/Libs/3.41.2/lib --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -Wl,--end-group
/Applications/STM32CubeIDE.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.macos64_1.0.200.202301161003/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: ./Core/Src/main.o: in function `main':
/Users/cristina.paniagua/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.12.0/PrototypeMica_v1/Debug/../Core/Src/main.c:103: undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:64: PrototypeMica_v1.elf] Error 1
"make -j9 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

The code is:

```
#include <sqlite3.h>

UART_HandleTypeDef hlpuart1;
#define PUTCHAR_PROTOTYPE int __io_putchar(int ch)


int main(void)
{
  
    sqlite3 *db;
    if (sqlite3_open("the.db", &db)) {
   printf("Could not open the.db\n");
   exit(-1);
 }



  while (1)
  {
 
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin (GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_7);

      printf("Test2\r\n");
      printf("%i\r\n", SQLITE_VERSION_NUMBER);

      HAL_Delay(1000);
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

As a side note, The SQLITE version number that I get is correct.

I also tried to add the .c directly to my directory, but the problem is that it does not compile because it is missing "sys/ioctl". Which I also tried to include as an import but without success.

I wonder if someone has any idea of how to fix the problem so I can start to implement my program.

Thanks.